# Associativity and piecewiseness

Tags: associativity

I have this confession: **Piecewise** definitions have always considerably annoyed me (with certain exceptions).

For $x,y\in (-1,1),$ let $x\circ y := xy -\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-y^2)}\in(-1,1).$

(The part that says $\text{“}{\in}\text{”}$ is a simple exercise, not part of the definition.)

**Proposision:**
If $\arccos x + \arccos y + \arccos z < \pi\quad\longleftarrow \text{ piecewise}$ 
then $x\circ(y\circ z) = (x\circ y)\circ z.$

The way the proposition is stated probably makes it clear how to prove it:
$$
x\circ y = xy-\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-y^2)} = \cos\alpha\cos\beta-\sin\alpha\sin\beta = \cos(\alpha+\beta)
$$
so it becomes mere associativity of addition. If the sum of the angles is more than a half-circle then we have a $\pm\sqrt{\cdots\cdots}$ issue, i.e. more piecewise stuff, and moreover we no longer have associativity.

So what is an elegant (in particular, short and without too much piecewise stuff) but completely elementary (say high-school-algebra-level) way to restate and prove the proposition without mentioning anything about trigonometric functions or otherwise constructing an isomorphism between this operation and another that everybody knows is associative?

(Maybe I would have answered this myself already if my distaste for piecewise definitions weren't making me gag. Maybe I'll post an answer below.)

Comment: You gag at the piecewiseness. I gag at trying to prove the associativity. Gross

Comment: @AdamRubinson : Why? You find the proof icky? Or because it ceases to be associative on a different "piece"? Or something else?

Comment: Because it looks icky...

Comment: @AdamRubinson : ok, So I'm not the only one who initially thought that. (And that's a reason for my posting this question.)

Answer (score 1):

Consider $S:=\{\,z\in\Bbb C\mid |z|=1\,\} $, show that $S$ is closed under multiplication, which is *of course* associative. Then for $x,y\in[-1,1]$ define
$$x\circ y:=\Re (zw)\qquad \text{where }z,w\text{ are the unique elements of }S\text{ with }x=\Re z, y=\Re w, \Im z\ge 0,\Im w\ge 0$$
Quickly check that this makes $x\circ y={}$(your formula) and conclude that $(x\circ y)\circ z=x\circ (y\circ z)$ holds at least when the complex products in the definitions of $x\circ y$ and of $y\circ z$ have non-negative imaginary part.

Comment: I'm not sure this satisfies the stated desiderata. More later . . . . .

Comment: @MichaelHardy Why so? This uses high school algebra and no trigonometry

Comment: I'm not sure yet. I'll think it over.

Comment: Maybe what I was really wondering is: Why does the most routine sort of high-school algebra applied to the defining expression not yield a simple proof (provided you pay suitable attention to the piecewise nature of some things)?

Comment: And now I'm thinking that what I really wanted was something more direct: i.e. don't construct an isomorphism to an operation that everybody knows is associative, but rather, just work with the definition as the question states it.